# Sum of series of fractions: $\frac{4}{1!}+ \frac{8}{2!}+ \frac{14}{3!} + \frac{22}{4!}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of the series:
>   $$\frac{4}{1!}+ \frac{8}{2!}+ \frac{14}{3!} + \frac{22}{4!}+\cdots$$

I am not able to understand how to proceed. The numerator terms have nothing in common which might result in an AP or GP.
Please guide me with the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the first order differences of the numerators, $4,6,8$ are increasing linearly (and hopefully continue doing so - there are few known terms), so that the general form of the numerators must be quadratic, $N_n:=an^2+bn+c$.

By extrapolation, the zero-th term is $2$, and as the second order difference is $2$, the general expression must be

> $$N_n=n^2+bn+2.$$

From $N_1=4$ you draw

> $$N_n=n^2+n+2$$

which fits all values.

Now the general term, a polynomial over a factorial

> $$\frac{N_n}{D_n}=\frac{n^2+n+2}{n!}$$

is a little embarrassing as we don't have just inverse factorials (as in the development of $e$). Anyway, we observe the simplification

$$\frac n{n!}=\frac1{(n-1)!},$$ and (more tricky), for the quadratic term,

> $$\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n(n-1)+n}{n!}=\frac1{(n-2)!}+\frac1{(n-1)!}.$$

Then we use the decomposition

> $$\frac{N_n}{D_n}=\frac{n^2+n+2}{n!}=\frac1{(n-2)!}+\frac2{(n-1)!}+\frac2{n!},$$

to establish

$$\begin{matrix}
e=&&&\color{white}+\frac1{0!}&+\frac1{1!}&+\frac1{2!}&+\cdots\\
2e=&&\color{white}+\frac2{0!}&+\frac2{1!}&+\frac2{2!}&+\frac2{3!}&+\cdots\\
2e=&\frac2{0!}&+\frac2{1!}&+\frac2{2!}&+\frac2{3!}&+\frac2{4!}&+\cdots&&
\\\hline
 5e=&\frac2{0!}&+\frac4{1!}&+\frac8{2!}&+\frac{14}{3!}&+\frac{22}{4!}&+\cdots\\
\end{matrix}$$

so that in the end

> $$5e=2+S.$$

Comment: I upvoted the answer because it is quite complete. But still I would like to point out that the OP asked for the approach not the full answer. I'm not sure if it is good for us to provide full answer right away.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat: I have hidden most of the results so that the OP can pick what he wants when he wants to. Hope this is better...

Answer (score 1):

Hint
Let $r$ denotes the index of the term, $r\geq 1$.

The numerator $a_r$ satisfies 
$$a_r=a_{r-1}+2r$$
with $a_0=2$.

Use method of difference to find the explicit expression for $a_r$.

Write you sum in summation notation and compare it to Taylor's series. You should eventually get $5e-2$ after some splitting and index changing.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = \frac{n^2 + n + 2}{n!}\\
\sum a_n = \sum\frac{n^2 + n + 2}{n!}\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2 - n}{n!} + \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{n!} + \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac {2}{n!}\\$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2 - n}{n!} = 0 + \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-2)!} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} = e\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{n!} = 2\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)!} = 2e\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac {2}{n!} = 2e- 2$

$5e-2$

Comment: In the 4th line, 2 appears where it should not be and then vanishes.